# Find command output to sort and then delete

Tags: linux, files, find, date, rm

I want to find some files based on some pattern in their paths and then I want to keep only the 3 latest files of that pattern and the others I want to delete.

Comment: Can the pattern occur anywhere in the "path", or does it have to occur in the file *name*?

Comment: what is the sort criteria if you say the 3 latest? Is latest = newest? If yes, based on last modification, creation or access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
echo rm -f ./**/*pattern*(.Dom[4,-1])
```

- `**/` any level of subdirectories
- `(...)` glob qualifiers to qualify the match on other criteria:
- `.`: regular files only
- `D`: include dot-files (hidden files) and look into hidden dirs
- `om`: order by modification time (newest to oldest)
- `[4,-1]`: from 4<sup>th</sup> to last (so skips the first 3).

(remove `echo` to actually do it)

For an equivalent using any POSIX shell and GNU utilities:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -name '*pattern*' -type f -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  sort -zrn |
  tail -zn +4 |
  cut -zd/ -f2- |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f)
```

(remove `echo` to actually do it)

With older versions of GNU utilities, you may need:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -name '*pattern*' -type f -printf '%T@/%p\0' |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  sort -rn |
  tail -n +4 |
  cut -d/ -f2- |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f)
```

Answer (score -1):

well, sorting requires a logic around it but so far:

```
# Create an array with the files you want to target
FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever")
# Get the total size of the array 
totalSize=${#FILES[@]}
# Detract 3 from total size to create a threshold
stopat=((${totalSize}-3))
# Declare a counter at 0
counter=0
# iterate file by file in the array
for FILE in "${FILES[@]}"
do
   # make sure that you do this until 3 files are left
   while [ ${counter} -le ${stopat} ]
   do
      rm -v ${FILE}
      ((counter++))
   done
done
```

when using `-name` you can use extended expressions, e.g. `*.sh` or `hello*.sh` or `*hello.sh` etc.

Please note the above command will delete all files but 3, use the command `sort` to sort the files as desired (either using size, creation or modification date) here:

`FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever")`

Comment: It would be nice if you actually showed *how* to use the `sort` command to sort a list of files by a file attribute like modification date/time.

Comment: you could actually exec ls -la and then pipe it with sort,
```FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever" -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -k 5 -n)```

1. you execute ```ls -la```

2. you pipe the output to ```sort``` and then ```-k 5``` to select the fifth column and ```-n``` for numeric sort. This will return smaller to bigger sort. If you want it bigger to smaller, then add a ```-r```

Comment: for mod-date, you would change it as this:
```FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever" -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -ltr```

Comment: and to clean the array and leave just the paths to files ```awk '{print $9}'``` for the 9th column
file-size: ```FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever" -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -k 5 -n) | awk '{print $9}'```
mod-date: ```FILES=$(find ${PATH_TO_FOLDER} -type f -name "whatever.whatever" -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}'```